# How persist an Polygon or Line in JSF app

Tags: jsf, polygon, openlayers

I'm trying persist an Polygon or multipolygon in JSF application. The database model, classes POJO has been OK, but in JSF/HTML forms, i dont know how proceed to submit an polygon or line string to my Java application.

To persist an openlayers Point i create an javascript action to send the XY to html inputs and after i submit to my java application.

In resume, i want now to make the HTML/JSF and Javascript code to can persist this features or yet an tutorial to help me.

Java model/pojo - ok
OpenLayers - ok
JSF and javascript proceedments - i dont know the 'way'

From now appreciate the support.

Answer (score 0):

For persisting polygons or other vector shapes, you need to serialize them to a vector format (e.g. GeoJSON, KML) first, then you can send the serialized string to the server and process/save it further.

Luckily, OpenLayers supports many popular vector formats out of the box - check the [vector formats example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/vector-formats.html) for further instructions.